# Working with DLL for model MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dll

Hi everyone I have an asp .NET MVC 4 project and the project has a model DLL.So Models folder is empty and the classes are in the ProjectName.DLL  How can I update the DLL without deleting old classes?

Let me make it clear:

I have a website that I can add pictures and text to. To do this normally I use models classes that are in the Models folder but in this project the other developer put classes in a separate DLL and now I have to update database tables. I need new table and I don't know how to reach DLL class file.

Is there anything like working with DLL as model? Or the other developer was trying to protect the models?

Comment: Can you please provide more detail on what exactly you want to update in the dll? As far as I know updating dll is not possible. However more detail is required to give you correct solution.

Comment: Have you used JetBrain's DotPeek before? This is free to download. Use this tool to decompile your dll and check the code. If the classes are partial, I guess you should be able to extend it. However I have never tried this approach with dll so I am not 100% sure.

Comment: hmm Okay I will try it but I'm not sure that should be done with decompile ? maybe codefirst things ? Im not sure :/

Answer (score -1):

In order to change a DLL or a library, you need to have the source code. If you do not currently have it, you need to ask the developer to give the source code to you. You can then make changes to it and if you are using code first migrations, your database tables will be changed accordingly.